# Move / add layout options to Preferences

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Currently we have the “**Enable**” / “**Disable Responsiveness**” and  “**Mobile**” options in the bottom left corner of pages:

[image: Responsiveness option]

Why not put this in “***Preferences***” (“Settings” => “SITE SETTINGS” => “Preferences”)? Or at least have it there in addition to where it is today?

[image]

It is somewhat counter-intuitive to have a setting that modifies layout be outside of “Preferences”, especially as other settings for the interface are there.

## Responsiveness

After the responsiveness-rollout I got stuck with the non-responsive layout on one page (Unix & Linux) - all others were in the new mode. The new layout has a fixed width of minimum `1264px` which is too wide for my taste, and results in horizontal scrolling if narrower. I have no idea when I clicked on the “Disable Responsiveness” and as there was no *Responsiveness* option in Preferences I had to start hunting. After meddling with cookies I got the responsive mode there as well.

Later I found where one *could* change it by searching forums for the cookie name `no-responsiveness` - but that is IMHO a somewhat long path for something that should be more user friendly. Again: have preferences in one place, not spread around.

---

## Mobile view

As for mobile-view, I never use that, but that should be under preferences as well IMO. I tried to enable it while on the *Settings* page, but as that page does not have a mobile view the layout did not change and the link at the bottom of the page still says “Mobile”.  First when navigating to a questions site the Mobile View kicks in and one gets a “Full site” option on the bottom of the page.

Now, if I had simply closed the page while being on the *Settings* page and then visited some SE site a couple of days later to find the “*new layout*”, I would likely have forgotten about clicking the “*Mobile*” link and thought something like “*wow, another rollout. Are these UI designers on acid or something?*” lol

As one can turn Mobile View on at for example the Settings page, this should also be reflected in the link at bottom by changing it to “full site”, and it's likely best to add it to the “Preferences” page as well.

As it is the de facto standard to put mobile/desktop view at the bottom of pages it's good to have it there as well of course, but - again - Preferences should reflect the viewing mode and give the options to switch to. It say *Preferences => Interface*, after all.

Comment: Well soon it won't be relevant, mobile theme is going away, and likely we won't be able to disable responsiveness too.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 If that is the case that should be debated long and hard in meta with initiative from SE IMO. With a **big** banner campaign to draw attention. It is a community ruled platform after all (`sarcasm` lol).

Comment: haha........ no. (aka one day we'll just notice those links are gone.)

Comment: Tagging this [tag:status-completed] since the changes indicated below have been live for quite a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we wrap up deprecating the mobile views, both the mobile toggle and disabling responsive buttons will be going away.

At this point, timing’s sliding a bit into January 2022.